# How can I use transform to extract a feature based on multiple conditions, using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select, by group, the minimum date when a condition is met and assign it to a new column:

```
Group    bool    date
  A       n      2000-01-01
  A       n      2000-03-02
  A       y      2000-04-10
  A       y      2001-01-01
  B       n      2000-02-20
  B       y      2000-03-15
  B       y      2000-04-27
  B       y      2001-01-10
```

This would become:

```
Group    bool    date          trigger_date
  A       n      2000-01-01    2000-04-10
  A       n      2000-03-02    2000-04-10
  A       y      2000-04-10    2000-04-10
  A       y      2001-01-01    2000-04-10
  B       n      2000-02-20    2000-03-15
  B       y      2000-03-15    2000-03-15
  B       y      2000-04-27    2000-03-15
  B       y      2001-01-10    2000-03-15
```

I've been trying to use groupby in combination with transform, but don't know how to get transform to take account of conditions based on other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change the `bool` column to actually booleans (also be careful with your names. DataFrame has a `bool` method):

```
In [51]: df['bool'] = df['bool'].replace({'n': False, 'y': True})
```

Finding the minimum dates is pretty easy. Use the `bool` column to index into `df`:

```
In [51]: dates = df[df['bool']].groupby("Group")['date'].first()

In [52]: dates
Out[52]: 
Group
A        2000-04-10
B        2000-03-15
Name: date, dtype: object


[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

There are probably a bunch of ways to set the values, but one is to set `Group` as the index and `join` the `dates`.

```
In [117]: df.set_index('Group').join(dates, rsuffix='_trigger')
Out[117]: 
        bool        date date_trigger
Group                                
A      False  2000-01-01   2000-04-10
A      False  2000-03-02   2000-04-10
A       True  2000-04-10   2000-04-10
A       True  2001-01-01   2000-04-10
B      False  2000-02-20   2000-03-15
B       True  2000-03-15   2000-03-15
B       True  2000-04-27   2000-03-15
B       True  2001-01-10   2000-03-15
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked except for joining bit. I had to convert the series to a dataframe and then perform a left merge: `pd.merge(df, dates, how='left', on='Group')`